# Multipy every five rows in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes in pandas of the following form:

```
         df1                                  df2
                column                                 factor
             0    2                                0     0.0
             1    4                                1     0.25
             2    12                               2     0.50
             3    5                                3     0.99
             4    4                                4     1.00
             5    15
             6    32
```

The work is to *sumproduct* every 5 row in df1 with df2 and put the new results in df3 (my actual data has about 500 rows in df1). The results should be like this:

```
        df3

            results     **description (no need to add this column)**
        0   15.95        df1.iloc[:4,0].dot(df2)
        1   24.46        df1.iloc[1:5,0].dot(df2)
        3   50.10        df1.iloc[2:6,0].dot(df2
```

Comment: Are you just wanting a loop to automate this process?

Comment: @sdhaus: yes, as mentioned I have about 500 rows in df1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

mx=df2.to_numpy()

df1.rolling(5).apply(lambda x: np.dot(x, mx), raw=True).iloc[4:]
```

Outputs:

```py
   column
4   15.95
5   24.46
6   50.10
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!